# Injecting HTML into existing web pages

Tags: javascript, html

I'm interested in the concept of injecting a bit of HTML into existing web pages to perform a service. The idea is to create an improved bookmarking system - but I digress, the specific implementation is unimportant. I'm quite new to web development and so I have no definite idea as to how to accomplish this, thought I have noticed a couple of possibilities.

- I found out I can right click > 'inspect element' and proceed to edit my browser's version of the HTML corresponding with the webpage I'm viewing. I assume that this means I can edit what I see and interact with. Could I possibly create a script that ran from a button on bookmarks bar that injected an Iframe which linked to a web service of my making? (And deleted itself after being used).
- Could I possibly use a chrome extension to accomplish this? I have no experience with creating extensions and so I have no clue what they're capable of - though I wouldn't be against learning.

Which of these would be best? If they are even valid ideas. Or is there another way that I've yet to know of?

EDIT: The goal is to have a user click a button in the browser if they would like to save this page. They are then presented an interface visually independent of the rest of the page that allows them to categorize this webpage according to their interests. It would take the current link, add some information such as a comment, rating, etc. and add it to the user's data. This is meant as a sort of side-service to a website whose purpose would be to better organize and display the browsing information of the user.

Comment: Could you clarify with more details about how you envision this system working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for examples of what kinds of questions to ask or _not_ ask.

Comment: What is this service you are looking to perform, sounds like you want to scrape web content. I would recommend looking into php if this is the case.

Comment: You are better of using chrome extension. There are many apps which inject html or modify them, so you could probably do what you want. However since your new to web development, this will be a bit of a challenge to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do this. You're asking about ***Bookmarklets***.

A bookmarklet is just a bookmark where the URL is a piece of JavaScript instead of a URL. They are very simple, yet can be capable of doing anything to a web page. Full JavaScript access.

A bookmarklet can be engaged on *any web page* -- the user simply has to click the bookmark(let) to launch it on the current page.

```
Bookmark    = "http://chasemoskal.com/"
Bookmarklet = "javascript:(function(){ alert('I can do anything!') })();"
```

That's all it is. You can create a bookmarklet link which can be clicked-and-dragged onto a bookmark bar like this:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){ alert('anything is possible') })();">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Bookmarklets can be limited in size, however, you can load an entire external script from the bookmarklet.

Comment: I intend to look into this, but as a cursory question/clarification: You're saying that there is a limited amount of space that I have in the bookmarklet for my script, yes? And that if I were to want a beefier amount of script, I could have the limited bookmarklet script call another actual script?

Comment: @pastrypuncher: Yes. Bookmarks and bookmarklets are just URLs, and URLs are not necessarily allowed to have unlimited length. It's my understanding that most modern browsers can handle URLs that are 2KB (2048 characters) or more, though when your bookmarklet script approaches that size, it's common to have the bookmarklet act simply as a loader, which loads in an external script (of any size) by appending a new `<script>` element to the current page.

Comment: [***HTML5 Outliner***](https://code.google.com/p/h5o/), or *h5o*, is one my favorite and most-used bookmarklets. It displays the current page's HTML5 Document Outline (highly important for SEO). A must-have for anyone in the web industry. For some reason it's really hard to find the bookmarklet's actual installation page from Google Code or GitHub, so I have it [**hosted here**](http://o-o-o.ca/outliner.html) for my own convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you refer to as *like an* `<iframe>`, so here are some steps that may help you, simply put:

1. Create an `XMLHttpRequest` object and make a request for a page trough it.
2. Make the `innerHTML` field of an element to hold the `resultString` of the previous request, *aka* the HTML structure.

Lets assume you have an element with the `id="Result"` on your html. The request goes like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://example.com/mydocument.html', true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        Result.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
};
req.send(null);
```

Here's an improved version in the form of [**a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tt3bE/1/).

When you're done, you can *delete* that *injected* HTML by simply:

```
Result.innerHTML = '';
```

And then anything inside it will be gone.

However, you can't make request to other servers due to `request policies`. They have to be under the same domain or server. Take a look at this: [Using XMLHttpRequest on MDN reference pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for more information.

Comment: Are `XmlHttpRequests` to other server not refused by most browsers? Only if the original page is in the mozilla.org domain, the query will succeed.