# getting Select tag value by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    $query="select * from category";
    $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
    echo'
    <select name="category" id="uni" >';
    //The select tag start here,It gets options from Database
    while($catrow=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo'<option value="">';
        echo'<option  value="'.$catrow['Id'].'">'.$catrow['Name'].
        '</option></form>';
    }
    echo'</select>';
?><br />
```

Now I have ajax codes like this,i know how to get input value with ajax but i dont know how to get select tags value with ajax.

I use this line of code for input types:

```
function checkUser() { 
    var str=document.form.category.value;

    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (xmlHttp==null) {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");

        return;
    }

    //this line is where I get inputs value,how can I get Select tag's?????!!!
    url='addserv.phptitle='+document.getElementById('title').value+document.getElementById('latitude').value+document.getElementById('ownerId').value;
    //alert(url);

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;

    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);

    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 ){ 
        var name = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use jQuery and make your life easier.

Comment: would you plz tell me how can I do it with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is echoing the correct markup and you want to append it to the DOM, then you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'something.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.someElement').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that doesn't require JQuery but only javascript would go like this:

```javascript
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://example.com/script.php', true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        YourElementId.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
};
req.send(null);
```

Where `YourElementID` would be the Id of the element you want to modify, like your `<select>` element and `script.php` should return either a JSON string (recommended) or directly the markup you want to put inside your `<select>` element.

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24416393/2625090) for more information.

**Update using JSON**:

Your php and the receiving document should be something like this:

**script.php**:

```php
<?php
    $responseArray = array(
        'option1' => 'option one'
        'option2' => 'option two'
        'option3' => 'option three'
        'option4' => 'option 4'
    );
    $jsonResponse = json_encode($responseArray);
    echo $jsonResponse;
?>
```

**document.html**:

```html
<header>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadOptions() {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', 'script.php', true);
            req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    responseObject = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                    for (var key in responseObject) {
                        Select.innerHTML += '<select value="'+key+'">'+responseObject[key]+'</select>';
                    }
                }
            };
            req.send(null);
        }
    </script>
</header>

<body onload="loadOptions();">
    <select id="Select">
    </select>
</body>
```